# Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Знаю, что много вопросов по этой теме, но на данный момент я перепробовал все способы предложенные в интернете по устранению этой проблемы, но ничего не исчезло.

Способы:

1. pod repo update -> pod update -> pod install
2. import FirebaseCore заместо import Firebase
3. FIRApp.configure() заместо FirebaseApp.configure()
4. Shift+Cmnd+Alt+K
5. Переоткрытие проекта
6. Перезапуск компьютера

Первоначально устанавливал Firebase строго по инструкции с сайта, но после появления данной ошибки перепробовал различные комбинации podfile. На данный момент он выглядит вот так:

```
    # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
    pod ‘Firebase/Core’
    # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
    # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
```

Изначально же он должен был выглядеть так:

```
    # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
    # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
```

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой и знает еще какие нибудь ее решения?

---

Переодически получается избавится от ошибки и запустить приложение, инициализация в Firebase консоли происходит, но при нажатии клавиш cmnd+shift+alt+k ошибка опять возвращается. Также когда ошибка пропадает модуль типа "Auth.auth()" все равно не доступен.

Comment: Выглядит словно нет bridge файла для работы кода Objective-C в Swift

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk, как оказалось данная ошибка в новой версии Firebase только есть. Откатился к 6.23 и все стало нормально.